# Customizar Mensagem Padrão de Erro no Login - Jetstream

Tags: autenticação, laravel-8

Estou iniciando meus estudos com o Laravel. Estou utilizando a versão 8 junto do Jetstream com o Livewire para a autenticação dos usuários.

No entanto, não consegui compreender como mudar a mensagem padrão de erro do Jetstream ("Whoops! Something went wrong.") durante o login "Whoops! Something went wrong."

A mensagem de credenciais incorretas eu consegui alterar através do arquivo `resources > lang > en > auth`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Essa é minha view de login:

```
<x-guest-layout>
<x-jet-authentication-card>
    <x-slot name="logo">
        <x-jet-authentication-card-logo />
    </x-slot>

    <x-jet-validation-errors class="mb-4" />

    @if (session('status'))
        <div class="mb-4 font-medium text-sm text-green-600">
            {{ session('status') }}
        </div>
    @endif

    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}">
        @csrf

        <div>
            <x-jet-label for="email" value="{{ __('Usuário') }}" />
            <x-jet-input id="email" class="block mt-1 w-full" type="text" name="username" :value="old('email')" required autofocus />
        </div>

        <div class="mt-4">
            <x-jet-label for="password" value="{{ __('Senha') }}" />
            <x-jet-input id="password" class="block mt-1 w-full" type="password" name="password" required autocomplete="current-password" />
        </div>

        <div class="flex items-center justify-end mt-4">
            <x-jet-button class="ml-4">
                {{ __('Entrar') }}
            </x-jet-button>
        </div>
    </form>
</x-jet-authentication-card>
```

Como posso mudar essa mensagem padrão de "Whoops! Something went wrong." para por exemplo "Ops, ocorreu um erro"?

Não sobrescrevi nenhum método do login, é o próprio Jetstream que está fazendo isso.

Agradeço desde já.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crie o arquivo resources/lang/en.json e adicione

```
{
    "Whoops! Something went wrong.": "Ops! Algo deu errado"
}
```

Aconselho também dar uma olhada no pacote ["lucascudo/laravel-pt-br-localization"](https://github.com/lucascudo/laravel-pt-BR-localization)